# How do I do this with Django objects.filter?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
MYTable.objects.filter( where id = 42, 55, 65, and 55)
```

and it returns a query set ?

Comment: Maybe you should precise your question because as adamk answered you can use the '__in' filter but as you specify '55' twice I think you are looking for something else...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
MYTable.objects.filter( id__in = [42,55,65,55] )
```